# ValueError: No object matches name: in Maya Python

Tags: python, maya

I have a code that returns an error of

```
ValueError: No object matches name: s
```

I'm not sure why it is looking for the object `s`.

The code is as follows

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

def createOffsetGrp(objSel):

    for obj in objSel:
        p = cmds.listRelatives(obj,parent=True)
        print (p)

createOffsetGrp('spine02_jnt')
```

By expectation, the print command should spit out `Spine01_jnt` which is the parent of the `Spine02_jnt`

Is there something I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to duck typing in Python, sometimes such errors can be hard to catch. What is happening here is your function is expecting an array as argument, but you are passing a string.

Python supports iterating over a string as well, by listing out individual characters, which is why it is looking for the `s` in `spine02_jnt`. Passing your string within an array should solve your problem:

```
createOffsetGrp(['spine02_jnt'])
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Works as expected. 
Thanks also for mentioning "duck typing". It's a new to me. 

Have a great day ahead!

Answer (score 1):

in addition of what crazyGamer, you can provide some support on string like this :

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

def createOffsetGrp(objSel):
    # isinstance is used to check the type of the variable :
    # i.e: isinstance(objSel, int)
    # basestring is a type combining unicode and string types
    if isinstance(objSel, basestring):
        objSel = [objSel]
    for obj in objSel:
        p = cmds.listRelatives(obj,parent=True)
        print (p)

createOffsetGrp('spine02_jnt')
```